# connect() does not re-render component

Tags: react-native, redux

a component dispatches an action which modifies the `Redux store` and the other component should get the changed state to props and rerender.

The thing is, the component gets the props, and they are correct and modified, but the component is never rerendered.

Could someone help, been stuck too much..

`Component who uses store:`

on mount it does a http request,
and should rerender when the state is changed.

```
class CalendarView extends Component {

 componentDidMount() {
   axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/bookings/get')
    .then(foundBookings => {
     this.props.getBookings(foundBookings);
    })
  .catch(e => console.log(e))
 }

 render() { 
  return (
   <Agenda
    items={this.props.items} 
    selected={this.props.today}
    maxDate={this.props.lastDay}
    onDayPress={this.props.setDay}
    renderItem={this.renderItem}
    renderEmptyDate={this.renderEmptyDate}
    rowHasChanged={this.rowHasChanged}
   />
  );
 }

 renderItem = (item) => {
   return (
     <View style={[styles.item, { height: item.height }]}>
       <Text>Name: {item.name} {item.surname}</Text>
       <Text>Time: {item.time}</Text>
     </View>
   );
 }

 renderEmptyDate = () => {
    return (
    <View style={styles.emptyDate}><Text>This is empty date!</Text></View>
    );
 }

 rowHasChanged = (r1, r2) => {
  console.log('hit')
  return true;
 }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
 return {
   today: state.app.today,
   lastDay: state.app.lastDay,
   items: state.app.items
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
 return {
   setDay: date => dispatch(appActions.setSelectionDate(date.dateString)),
   getBookings: data => dispatch(appActions.getBookings(data)), 
  }
 }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CalendarView);
```

`Action Dispatching:`

dispatches an action which modifies the state

```
onSubmit = (name, surname, selectionDate, selectionTime) => {
   axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/bookings/create', {
     bookerName: name,
     bookerSurname: surname,
     bookerTime: selectionTime,
     date: selectionDate
   }).then(savedBookings => {
    this.props.createBooking(savedBookings);
    this.props.navigator.pop({
      animationType: 'slide-down',
   });
  }).catch(e => console.log(e))
 }

const mapStateToProps = state => {
 //...
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
   createBooking: data => dispatch(appActions.createBooking(data))
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NewBookingScreen);
```

`Reducer:`

```
case types.CREATE_BOOKING: {
  const { date , bookings } = action.savedBookings.data;
  let dateArr = state.items;
  // formatting a booking how needed
  Object.keys(dateArr).forEach(key => {
    if (key == date) {
      dateArr[key] = [];
      bookings.map(oneBooking => {
        dateArr[key].push({
          name: oneBooking.bookerName,
          surname: oneBooking.bookerSurname,
          time: oneBooking.bookerTime,
          height: Math.max(50, Math.floor(Math.random() * 150))
        });
      })
    }
  });
  return {
    ...state,
    items: dateArr
  };
}
```

full repo if needed: `https://github.com/adtm/tom-airbnb/tree/feature/redux`

Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reducer is mutating the state, so `connect` thinks nothing has changed.  In addition, your call to `map()` is wrong, because you're not using the result value.

Don't call `push()` on an array unless it's a copy.  Also, please don't use any randomness in a reducer.

For more info, see [Redux FAQ: React Redux](https://redux.js.org/faq/react-redux#react-not-rerendering) ,[Immutable Update Patterns](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns), and [Roll the Dice: Random Numbers in Redux](https://daveceddia.com/random-numbers-in-redux/) .

Comment: Thank You very much for the answer and resources, fixed it!